# How to compare number with all number in List not loop List?

Tags: c#

I have a problem in compare number with all item in `List`.

Because in bellow code. You can see when `i = 1`, the `if-else` statement will fail. Because it is `foreach` all values.

First values are 0. I don't want this case.

Have any method to compare `i` variable to with all values?

Thanks.

```
List<int> values = new List<int>();
private void CheckCondition()
{
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        foreach (int num in values)
        {
            if (i == num || i<num)
                continue;
            else
            {
                values.Add(i);
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
            break;
        else
            continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is the expected result (say "The expected resuslt is `List<int> values` with ... values")?

Comment: `foreach(...in values) { ... values.Add() }` - is bad idea. Can you describe in words the logic? What `CheckCondition()` is supposed to do?

Comment: `else continue;` is redundant

Comment: I want compare `i` with all values in `values`. Because `if(i==num || i<num)` will fail when `i>1`. The `values = { 0, 1, ... 5 }`, using `foreach` it must run first item `values = 0`.

Comment: lets say your values list is `{2,3,4}`. What do you expect check values to be after `CheckCondition` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to add `i` to `values` if there is no `i` in that list?
Use `FindIndex` to check if list contains i it will return the index. If it is not, it will return -1.

```
List<int> values = new List<int>();
private void CheckCondition()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int idx = values.FindIndex(item => item == i || item > i);
        if(idx == -1)
        {
           values.Add(i);
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @curarpickt. It's exactly I want. Working for me.

Comment: instead of using `values.FindIndex` use `values.Contains/Any` - you don't really need the index - just to know if it exists

Comment: @GiladGreen there is a condition to check if that item exists `if (i == num || i<num)`. That's why I use FindIndex.

Comment: Seems like the op wanted to append only the first value between [0,4] that meets the flag. `if (flag) break`

Comment: `bool flag = false;` is *redundant*; `if (idx < 0)` is more accurate then `if (idx == -1)`

Answer (score 1):

This code will look for each value of `i` in your collection of values

```
List<int> values = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
for(int i = 0; i< num; i++)
{
    if(values.Contains(i)) 
    {
        //Do the code you want
    }
}
```

If you want to check some other condition regarding the list and the `i` you can:

```
List<int> values = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
for(int i = 0; i< num; i++)
{

    if(values.Any(item => item == i || item > i))
    {
        //Do the code you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Describe what you want. I do can answer youre question regarding to check if an item is in the List

```
List<int> values = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};
bool containsItem = values.Contains(2);
```